# ¿Como utilizar función: mysqli_real_escape_string() con arreglo de inputs recibido del formulario?

Tags: php, mysqli

Buscaba la manera de escapar caracteres especiales en arrays de inputs que son recibidos por este archivo, ¿cuál debe ser la forma correcta de escaparlos?. Al tener `$asistencias` intentando escapar obtengo error: `Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in`

El arreglo de inputs es recibido en `$asistencias`, solo tengo problema con las variables que son arreglos traídos del formulario
por ejemplo: numsesiones= 30 (este es un solo valor de input), asistencias [25,28,30,27....]

```js
elseif ( isset($_POST['numsesiones'])  && !empty($_POST['asistotales']) )   { 
    $conexion =  conectar();
    $idgrupo      = $_POST['idgpo'][0]; //arreglo idgrupo[] siempre es el mismo
    $alumnos     = $_POST['idalumno']; //arreglo idalumno[]
    $asistencias  = $_POST['asistotales']; //valores de arreglo recibido
    $numsesiones  = $_POST['numsesiones'];  //1 valor recibido de un input

       $asistencias = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $asistencias);
```

Comment: toma el valor en la iteración de un ciclo:  `$alumno_asistencias = $asistencias[$a];` Luego ese valor es usado como operando en una regla de 3, el resultante de esa operación es lo que guarda, la sentencia sql

Comment: Entonces lo que deberías hacer es aplicar la función dentro de ese ciclo, es decir, `$alumno_asistencias = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $asistencias[$a]);`

Comment: Te recomiendo que investigues sobre [PDO](http://php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php) y las [sentencias preparadas](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php) esto ayudara a que tu código tenga varios años más de vida útil y no tienes que preocuparte por la inyección de código SQL, si te parece fácil podrías usar [Doctrine DBAL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html)

Comment: tiene razón, gracias saludos

Comment: Como ya se ha dicho: esa función no te ayuda a escapar de la inyección SQL, por eso fue declarada obsoleta. El uso de **PDO bien configurado** o MySQLi usando en ambos consultas preparadas es la manera más segura de consultar tu BD. Si te interesa para más adelante tengo una clase para PDO que puede serte  útil.   Saludos

Comment: gracias,saludos. Tiene razón

Answer (score 1):

Si tu intencion es aplicar la misma funcion a todos los valores de un array la solucion seria utilizar la funcion [array_map](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-map.php).

```
$asistencias = array_map('mysqli_real_escape_string', $asistencias);
```

Esto protegeria tu base de datos de inyecciones SQL pero dependiendo de como utilizes los datos que guardes podria ser vulnerable a otro tipo de ataques. Si los datos que se guardan en la base de datos se utilizan posteriormente para hacer calculos o para mostrar datos a otros usuarios deberias validar cada tipo de dato antes de guardarlo. Por ejemplo, los valores numericos se podrian validar como enteros y para los string podrias filtrar los caracteres no validos.

Sumado a esto si estos campos no deberian contener codigo HTML añadiria tambien la funcion [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strip-tags.php).

```
$asistencias = array_map('mysqli_real_escape_string', $asistencias);
$asistencias = array_map('strip_tags', $asistencias);
```

Comment: de acuerdo, muchas gracias

Answer (score -3):

La función [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) ya esta obsoleta en PHP 5.5.0 y eliminada en PHP 7.0.0.

```
$asistencias = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $asistencias);
```

Asumo que $asistencias es un string, porque he probado en mi maquina y me funciona. Lo que podría ser es que venga vacío el valor o que venga por GET, en vez de POST.

```
$asistencias  = $_GET['asistotales']; //valores de arreglo recibido
```

Una forma rápida de depurar tus valores.

```
var_dump(asistencias);
die();
```

También podes usarlo de esta manera más practica.

```
// Consulta
$consulta = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='%s' AND password='%s'",
            mysql_real_escape_string($usuario),
            mysql_real_escape_string($contraseña));
```

Como no tengo una consulta de tu base de datos, coloque un ejemplo cualquiera. La idea es usar dentro de un consulta la función mysql_real_escape_string

Si asistencias es un array podes hacer lo siguiente:

```
$getarr = array();
$asistencia = array(25,28,30,27);
foreach($asistencias AS $val) {
    $getarr[] = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $val);
}
echo json_encode($getarr);
```

Comment: son valores númericos enteros los de asistencias, ¿Para php 5.6 ya no funciona tampoco mysqli_real_escape?

Comment: o ¿alguna otra forma de proteger los campos contra inyección? en l versión php 5.6

Comment: Si funciona pero seguramente te podría salir un warning. Pudiste depurar tus variables?? yo creo que ese es el problema. En cuanto a la función, pero mencionarte nomas para que sepas. Por ahora preocupate en solucionar el problema y después fijate de lo demás.

Comment: seguiré verificando, los valores si estaban pasando bien hasta que intente colocar la función para escapar el arreglo, fue que me detecto el error,

Comment: @ArmandoArellano con todas las variables estas teniendo problemas??

Comment: solo con las que vienen como arreglos de inputs del formulario. Las que quería escapar de caracteres eran la  de asistencias que es arreglo y la de numsesiones, pero esta ultima es solo un input, no habria problema porque no es array de inputs

Comment: y podrías dar un ejemplo de como viene. Entonces ese es el problema. Agrega en tu pregunta porque esa información es muy importante

Comment: lo puse en la descripción

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50669/discussion-between-josego-and-armando-arellano).

Comment: La función [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) (sin `i`) fue declarada obsoleta, pero la función [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) (con `i`) no

Comment: En absoluto **mysqli_real_escape_string** esta obsoleta, solo la vieja mysql_real_escape_string ( sin la i) es la que quedo obsoleta.